# Is it possible to run Phalcon project on shared hosting?

Tags: phalcon

I know to install Phalcon framework on a server I need root/administrator access on the server. But the shared hosting providers don't provide any ssh or root access. Then, How can I run my Phalcon project in shared hosting? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

No solution to shared hosting other than to find a shared hosting provider that supports it.

Official answer here:
http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/929/phalcon-on-shared-hosting

Answer includes list of shared hosting providers that support phalcon.

My advice: Don't use shared hosting. Check out VPS hosting which provides 'some' guarantee of allocation of resources. Price can be less in many cases unless you are using free shared hosting. Either way, its better to get acquainted with setting up a VPS sooner than later.